# Grafana alert always gives no_data

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I'm trying to set an alert in Grafana as soon as the value is outside the range 16 to 36. I'm using influxDB

I have a simple query (A):

```
SELECT "value" FROM "temp"
```

The graph is shown correctly.

My alert config looks like this:
WHEN last() OF query(A, 1s, now) IS OUTSIDE RANGE 16 TO 36

But if I evaluate the Test Rule, I always get the state no_data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any errors in the Grafana server log? Queries for alerts are executed from the backend (the graph that you see is from a query that is executed from your browser) so there might be a permissions or DNS problem.

Comment: No errors, just an info "Alert Rule returned no data"

Comment: Can you see what data is returned from InfluxDB using the network tab in the Chrome Developer Tools. It is probably not returning any data. Instructions here: https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-troubleshoot-metric-query-issues/50/2

Comment: There is no data returned. All points look the following way: `[null,1495208819]`. But if I run the query on the database itself, there are results. How does grafana evaluate the parameters for the query (1s, now)?

Comment: That query is checking the data for the last second (now - 1 second). Sounds to me like that query will nearly always be null unless you are writing data to the db every second. Usually, I would use at least 5 minutes as it would be very flappy having such a small interval.

Comment: Changing the time parameter does not help.

Comment: Just so it can help someone: I had a similar issue but the query was something like `SELECT ... WHERE host =~ /$server$/ AND $timeFilter ...`. Since I have only one server I removed the `host =~ /$server$/` and it worked. I guess `server` was not defined.

Answer (score 3):

Well.. 3 years later.. =)

I had this same problem. To fix this, go to your Influx server and type:

```
use <databasename>
show field keys
```

The command "show field keys" will return something like this:

```
name: table_name
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
value    string
```

The problem is the column **fieldType** need to be **float** and not string. In my case, I dropped the database and created it again. And I inserted as decimal.

Comment: I have the same issue as OP on a field that’s already a `float`